# Can I invite people to my party if I wait for them to join the Normandy?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I accidentally started the Citadel DLC and I went through the entire thing up until I have to send out the invitations to the party.

The thing is, I don't have Tali yet and I haven't even started the quest to get her back yet.

Can I start that quest now and still invite her to the party? I think she would enjoy an invitation but I'm wondering if it's worth it if I can even invite her at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. 
You need to finish Tali's arc to Priority: Rannoch. Then you can invite her to the party. You can also get to see her custom encounter of watching a movie.

Comment: First time I played after getting the DLC I tried doing it before finishing the Rannoch business to try and get Legion is as well. Sadly it doesn't work and neither was an option

Comment: The Citadel quest chain needs to be completed in one go. But after that and before the party invites, I usually go and do other missions till the assault on Cerberus HQ.

Comment: Cool thanks, getting Tali tonight and partying it up!